# can't install apport, software update failed due to the error

Tags: 16.04, dpkg

software update failed due to error with apport install/update:

```
Could not install '/var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.10_all.deb'

Subtask failed with error 139.

The upgrade will continue but the '/var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.10_all.deb' package may not be in a working state. Please consider submitting a bug report about it.
```

## error messages from the command line:

```
Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.10_all.deb ...
Segmentation fault
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 139
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.10_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 139
Segmentation fault
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 139
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.10_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

==
Seems the subtask try to update apport with an older version of deb package, and system failed it.

This is happening recently with a ubuntu base security update package contains apport bug fixes.And this buggy package blocks all software updates.

Comment: The lines `Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.10_all.deb ...
Segmentation fault` and `dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Segmentation fault` makes me wonder if your system is broken on a deeper level.  Have you made any major changes recently? Upgraded Python? Does `dpkg-deb --contents /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.10_all.deb` Seg fault,  too?

Comment: Didn't change the Python recently.  Nor any major changes before this error occurred.      
Tried :dpkg-deb --contents /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.10_all.deb 
it works with this command.

Comment: I tried to remove the sources.list and redo the update/upgrade, but now I got error with command 'sudo apt-get upgrade' , it always complains :

E: The package apport needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

What is apport and how can I bypass it?

Comment: I don't think it's python, I have this same issue on a fresh install of ubuntu 17.